# Можно ли сделать неполную десериализацию XML в c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, сериализация

Допустим, есть некоторый XML.

В этом XML много разных узлов и атрибутов, но нужны мне только определенные, поэтому у меня класс готов только для определенных узлов.
Могу ли я сделать неполную десериализацию , так что бы интересующие меня элементы успешно десериализировались, а не нужные где-нибудь запомнились, но при сериализации у меня успешно восстановился исходный XML?

Иными словами, есть XML такого вида:

```
        <root>
    <node/>
    <node2/>
    <node3/>
    <ExtraNode>
        <node/>
        <node2/>
        <node3/>
    </ExtraNode>
</root>
```

Я хочу десериализовать только root/ExtraNode и все вложенные туда узлы.
Возможно ли сделать десериализацию только этих узлов, сделать некоторые изменения в этих узлах(Добавить, удалить, изменить) и сериализовать в исходный XML?

Comment: А почему не десериализировать всё, поменять только нужные узлы и сериалиизировать назад? У вас проблемы с производительностью?

Comment: Нет, просто xml передается из вне и там может быть все что угодно к чему я могу быть не готовым, но я точно знаю что там будут нужные мне узлы. Или существует какая нибудь динамическая десриализация?

Comment: Ну да, в `XDocument`, как в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

На примере `XDocument`.

Загрузить все в `XDocument`:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("SomeXmlFile.xml");
```

Внести изменения:
Ищем нужные

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elements =
    from el in doc.Elements("SomeElement")
    select el;
```

для найденных выполняем десериализацию и сериализацию

```
foreach (XElement el in elements)
{
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeClass));
    SomeClass obj = (SomeClass)xs.Deserialize(el.CreateReader());
    //что-то делаем с объектом
    xs.Serialize(el.CreateWriter(),obj);
}
```

Выгрузить в файл:

```
doc.Save("SomeXmlFile.xml");
```

Классы `XElement` и `XDocument` имеют массу средств для работы со своими внутренностями. Подробнее про возможности - в MSDN, начинать [**отсюда**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx).

Еще есть класс `XmlDocument` и сопутствующие ему классы. Более старый, и немного более громоздкий, хотя на любителя, я, в свое время, начинал именно с него. Подробно читать [**тут**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Можно пример этого?

Comment: @iluxa1810 Нужно просто внести изменения в отдельные узлы? я правильно понял вопрос?

Comment: Да. Туда входит: добавление узлов, удаление узлов, исправление атрибутов и т п

Comment: @iluxa1810 да, сейчас добавлю. вообще в MSDN довольно много примеров по работе с этими классами, сам на них учился.

Comment: @iluxa1810 добавил простой пример и ссылки на документацию. Вообще .NET очень мощно поддерживает XML аж двумя наборами классов. `XDocument` до кучи еще и LINQ понимает, точнее для LINQ создавался.

Comment: @iluxa1810 добавил собственно сериализацию из отдельного элемента документа в объект и обратно.